# C# VOID parameters (list of options)

Tags: c#, function, void

i am writing a function that will return a image.
The input params are:

URL
* Width
* Height
* Format (imagetype) JPEG, PNG, BMP

- Are optional.

The problem i have is that i don't want to make "Format" as a STRING and then use a switch case on it.

I want to declare it in the function that JPEG, PNG, BMP is what you can choose, nothing else!

I have found a exempel where you create a class with ENUM and put your option there. And you add that to the function as a reference.

But i am quite sure that i have read that you can put the option values direct in the function without using a class, so if that is possible? How do you do that?

Comment: So you basically want something like an enum but not enum?

Comment: Are you asking "How do is write a switch staement with string based case clauses?". If so read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/06tc147t.aspx

Comment: Whats wrong with a vanilla enum? This is pretty much exactly what they are for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare an `enum` like this:

```
enum FileType
{ JPEG, PNG, BMP }
```

And use it in your method:

```
public void Method( string url = null
                  , int? width = null
                  , int? height = null
                  , FileType format = FileType.PNG
                  )
{
    // use a switch to check the value of format
}
```

As a bonus, you have your optional fields, filled with defaults if not supplied. For the `height` and `width` you could take the actuals from the source image, if any. Else I would make them `int` instead of nullable `int` (`int?`).

Comment: Since width and height are supposed to be optional, I should make them nullable, not default to 128.

Comment: To me, it makes more sense than a value of 128. Since the first input parameter is an URL, I assumed a default value of null would signal the code to use the source width and height. But then again,  Assumptions are...

Comment: @MarkO: Updated the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! In the future what is the search word for this?

Comment: `enum`, `optional parameters` I would guess.